# Selenium Path python

Tags: python, selenium

My English is bad because i'm french, sorry.
Hello
I want to get starting with selenium, but when I write

```
webdriver = webdriver.chrome()
```

The path isn't good.
I hope you help me, i had search, but i dont find.
My python folder:

```
C:\Users\ano\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32
```

The chromedriver.exe folder:

```
C:\Users\ano\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\selenium\chrome
```

I get the error when i write:

```
from selenium import webdriver

chrome_path = r"C:\Users\ano\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\selenium\chrome\chromedriver.exe"
driver = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_path)
```

I need to change the folder of the chromedriver? 
Thanks for your help.
Have a nice day

Error message:

```
    "C:\Users\FAMILLE ano\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\python.exe" "C:/Users/FAMILLE ano/PycharmProjects/Project/WebDriver/MyFirstSelenium.py"
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/FAMILLE ano/PycharmProjects/Project/WebDriver/MyFirstSelenium.py", line 3, in <module>
    driver = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_path)
  File "C:\Users\FAMILLE ano\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\chrome\webdriver.py", line 69, in __init__
    desired_capabilities=desired_capabilities)
  File "C:\Users\FAMILLE ano\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 151, in __init__
    self.start_session(desired_capabilities, browser_profile)
  File "C:\Users\FAMILLE ano\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 240, in start_session
    response = self.execute(Command.NEW_SESSION, parameters)
  File "C:\Users\FAMILLE ano\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 308, in execute
    self.error_handler.check_response(response)
  File "C:\Users\FAMILLE ano\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\errorhandler.py", line 194, in check_response
    raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: unknown error: cannot find Chrome binary
  (Driver info: chromedriver=2.33.506120 (e3e53437346286c0bc2d2dc9aa4915ba81d9023f),platform=Windows NT 10.0.15063 x86_64)


Process finished with exit code 1
```

Comment: Can you post the error message that it gives you?

Comment: Why don't you try putting the path without `r`?

Comment: @ammarx because i have whitout the r i have a error

Comment: @Jebby i added the error in the question

Comment: from ' unknown error: cannot find Chrome binary ', it seems selenium can't find the chrome.exe.  Did you install the chrome in default location on Windows: "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe",  if Not you need to add the parent folder of chrome.exe into PATH environment variable.  Then run your script in new command window

Comment: @Jebby if i don't change the folder of chromedriver.exe, i get the chrome driver folder and i add it to the path ? and what's the link i write for opening the chromedriver in python ? thanks

Comment: @Tifiloow I added an answer below. Follow the steps I provided and it should open a new window, load google, then close.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you are seeing the error as `WebDriverException: Message: unknown error: cannot find Chrome binary` which means the **`chromedriver.exe`** binary is unable to find the **`chrome.exe`** binary.

### Solution :

- Uninstall **`Google Chrome`** from your system through **`Revo Uninstaller`**.
- Confirm there is no trace of **`Google Chrome`** in your **`System`** and **`User`** variables as well as **`Windows Registry`**.
- Run **`CCleaner`** to wipe out all the `**OS**` chores.
- Take a **`System Reboot`**
- Install the latest version of **`Google Chrome`**.
- Download the latest version of **`chromedriver.exe`** from this [**link**](https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/chromedriver/) and place it anywhere within your system.
- While mentioning the absolute path of **`chromedriver.exe`**, either use the single front slash `(/)` along with the raw `(r)` switch or the escaped back slash `(\\)`.
- Here is your own code with some simple tweaks :

  ```
  from selenium import webdriver
  driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=r'C:\your_system_path\chromedriver.exe')
  ```

Answer (score 0):

First off, follow these steps

> 1. Download the latest chromedriver binary from [HERE](https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/chromedriver/downloads)
> 2. Unzip the archive.
> 3. Move the `chromedriver.exe` to your Windows directory. The path to chromedriver should now be something like
>      `C:\\Windows\chromedriver.exe`

Now open a Python interpreter and try this:

```
from selenium import webdriver
import time


# Create an instance of the Chrome webdriver.
# You don't need a path here, since chromedriver.exe
# is in your Windows directory
driver = webdriver.Chrome()

# Get google.com and close 5 seconds after it is loaded
driver.get("http://google.com")
time.sleep(5)
driver.close()
```

This worked for me. (Opened a new Chrome window, loaded google, and closed after 5 seconds)

I hope this helps. If it did, please click the check-mark to accept this as the solution.

Comment: i write the code you said, and i change the path of chromedriver.exe, the new path of chromedriver is the following : C:\Windows\chromedriver.exe, but again i get a error message, it don't find chromedriver, thanks.